# Why wasn't Sid surprised when he pulled a cowboy out of the claw machine?

Tags: plot-explanation, toy-story

In Toy Story, Sid Phillips pulls Woody and Buzz out of the claw machine. I am wondering why Sid wouldn't find it suspicious to pull a cowboy out of a machine directed specifically for outer space toys. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd be surprised he won at a claw game in the first place. Those things are rigged.

Answer (score 7):

1. Sid *is* quite pleasantly surprised when he sees Buzz among the spacemen:

> **A Buzz Lightyear? No way!**

And later Woody:

> **Alright! Double prizes!**

2. Sid is a kid, and when kids are offered a free toy, they don't usually question it or stop to think about some slight inconsistencies. They'll just be happy to get *any* toy.
3. Sid has also been established as a savage boy who only wants toys so he could destroy them. He would care even less about the *kind* of toy that comes his way.
4. Claw machines contain [many kinds of toys](https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2852/9988615093_62aba90887_b.jpg) and I doubt their maintenance is incredibly rigorous. Some other toys *could* end up in there, either by accident or intentionally.

So given all of the above, what's the point in stopping the plot and having Sid note that this is weird, when it's not that weird to begin with and doesn't seem like something Sid would wonder anyway? That would seem like a rather superfluous moment, to be honest.